# Passing text to a combobox VB6

Tags: combobox, vb6

Have a question - I'm having an issue with passing .text to a combobox that has a style set to LIST. I'm not sure why the issue is. Basically have a combobox that's populated with a lot of data. To make matter simple, I've created an additional form where user has a whole screen from where they are able to choose an item. The new form has the SAME EXACT items that combobox has - so when I pass the text from the new form to Combobox 2.0 - I get an error 380 - text propery is not set correctly

Comment: Show your code and combobox properties

Answer (score 1):

are you using the .AddItem method to add your text items?

Comment: Yes I am. I have a combobox leader and that's how i add the items. For some reason though, if there is a value in the combobox and i try to .text = new value - it gives me an error. So basically what i do is once i left the combobox form to go to another form I set the .listindex=-1 and when I come back with a text value it lets me insert it

Comment: Show your code and combobox properties - you can't set cbo.Text - that's a readonly property in List style combobox